# Change legend items in plot-metrics chart of roc curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, legend, roc, auc

I'm using plot-metrics library for creating ROC chart.

I'm trying to create the chart for three different models I have created in order to compare between them and show which model is the best one.
The problem is that I cannot edit the legend and I get the random guess appear 3 times + cannot edit the item names in the legend (e.g model 1, model 2 and model 3).

this is how I generated this chart:

```
from plot_metric.functions import BinaryClassification
# Visualisation with plot_metric
bcl = BinaryClassification(y_test, predictions1, labels=["TREAT1", "TREAT2"])
bcrf = BinaryClassification(y_test, predictions2, labels=["TREAT1", "TREAT2"])
bcxgb = BinaryClassification(y_test, predictions3, labels=["TREAT1", "TREAT2"])

# Figures
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
bcl.plot_roc_curve(plot_threshold=False,c_roc_curve='b', title='Receiver Operating Characteristic')
bcrf.plot_roc_curve(plot_threshold=False,c_roc_curve='green')
bcxgb.plot_roc_curve(plot_threshold=False,c_roc_curve='purple')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I thought there is parameter for this (True ot false for the random guess) but there is only for the threshold and other parameters and also couldn't find any parameter for the legend:
https://plot-metric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

My end goal: to change the legend items names and not to have the Random guess 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution with a simple plot work-around (I tried putting your variables/colors in the correct places):

```py
import numpy as np

# Get data and labels (via hidden figure)
plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_visible(False)
fpr1, tpr1, _, auc1 = bcl.plot_roc_curve(plot_threshold=False,c_roc_curve='r')
fpr2, tpr2, _, auc2 = bcrf.plot_roc_curve(plot_threshold=False,c_roc_curve='g', ls_random_guess='')
fpr3, tpr3, _, auc3 = bbcxgb.plot_roc_curve(plot_threshold=False,c_roc_curve='m', ls_random_guess='')

# Get series labels as numpy list
_, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = np.array(labels)                     

# Create plot yourself
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))                                     # Init figure
plt.plot(fpr1, tpr1, 'b', linewidth=3)                                # Plot 1st ROC Curve
plt.plot(fpr2, tpr2, 'g', linewidth=3)                                # Plot 1st ROC Curve
plt.plot(fpr3, tpr3, 'purple', linewidth=3)                           # Plot 1st ROC Curve
plt.plot(np.arange(0,1.01,0.01), np.arange(0,1.01,0.01), linewidth=3) # Plot dashed guess line
plt.legend([labels[0],labels[2],labels[4],labels[1]])                 # Fix legend entries
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate [FPR]')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate [TPR]')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')                        # Add appropriate title
```

**My code works as follows:**

1. Create a 1x1 (or tiny) hidden figure for plotting
2. Run the plot_roc_curve and get the FPR, TPR, and AUC values for each of your 3 models
3. Use `plt.gca()` and `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to get the legend entries for the hidden plot.
4. Create a new (non-hidden) plot and plot the data from #2 as multiple series
5. Modify the legend entries acquired from #3 to only have 1 'Random guess' label and set this to the legend of the newly created figure.

**Here is a sample figure using plot-metric's sample code/data:**
[image: Sample_Figure]